# How to get object from location.search which formalized from jQuery.param() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, location

I want to get the object from URL search params which formalized via `$.param()` method.

For example, i construct the URL like this when user filter a table column

```
  const filter = {filter: {name: 'John Doe', age: 40}};

  $(location).attr('search', $.param(filter));
  // URL localhost:3000/users?filter%5Bname%5D=John+Doe&filter%5Bage%5D=40
```

Then he gives the link his friend, he put it in browser and go to page.

The question is how can i get object from `?filter%5Bname%5D=John+Doe&filter%5Bage%5D=40` like
`{filter: {name: 'John Doe', age: 40}}`

Comment: To turn form-urlencoded values in to an object, see [this specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2880929/519413) of the duplicate